# Equivalent key to alt+backspace on Linux

Tags: keyboard

In Linux and bash I use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>bksp</kbd> to remove the word before the cursor.

On mac the <kbd>option / alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> does not work.

e.g If you typed `aaaa bbbb` you will get `aaaa` afterwards

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this functionality is provide by "readline", http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3. Most of keys are same as Emacs,

1. so, you can type <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to delete the word just before the cursor
2. or for example,you can change the preferences of the terminal.app, use option as Meta key. <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> do the same thing

Comment: Cool! I didn't know ^w even when I'm using linux ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>?

Comment: Does not work in iTerm2 ... I typed "aaaa bbbb" and pressing that key results in "aaaa bbb" but I expected "aaaa"

Comment: That may be a limitation of iTerm. I don't have it, so im not sure. Does it work for you in other programs?